# Prove or disprove Any subgroup of differentiable lie group is analytic submanifold?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, lie-groups

I have made a research in the web to know more about analyticity of of lie group and to give a convinced answer to this question which i have accrossed it in my research which is stated the following :Prove or disprove Any subgroup of differentiable lie group is analytic submanifold ?

Comment: Could you explain what you call an analytic submanifold of a differentiable Lie group?

Comment: What about the rationals?

Answer (score 3):

Proof in Bourbaki ([1972](https://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=573068), Chap. 3, §4, [Prop. 9](https://books.google.com/books?id=brSYF_rB2ZcC&pg=PA290)) or Godement ([1982](https://ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=679860), Chap. 6, [Thm 11](https://books.google.com/books?id=bAbVDgAAQBAJ&pg=PA272)). Beware that “submanifold” is to be understood as what’s often called *initial submanifold* nowadays (it need not have the subspace topology — cf. Thomas Rot’s example).